# Create a new column based on values of time-series data in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I created a date range in Pandas as follows:

```
new_range = pd.date_range(start="2015-1-1", end="2015-12-31")
required_df = pd.DataFrame(new_range)
required_df.head()
```

This results in a dataframe:

```
    Start Date
0   2015-01-01
1   2015-01-02
2   2015-01-03
3   2015-01-04
4   2015-01-05
```

Now I would like to add a new column where the date will be a range starting from value of Date field in the row ending on the last date of the year. The resulting Dataframe should be something like this:

```
    Start date   End Date
0   2015-01-01  2015-01-02
1   2015-01-01  2015-01-03
2   2015-01-01  2015-01-04
.................
N   2015-01-01  2015-12-31
N+1 2015-01-02  2015-01-03
N+2 2015-01-02  2015-01-04
.................
N+M 2015-12-30  2015-12-31
```

I can use for loop to loop through each value in `data_range` and create new columns based on that. But I think there must be some efficient solution in Pandas to accomplish this.

Comment: Why is `End Date` equal to `2015-01-02` in `row` `0` and `2015-12-31` in `row` `N` for the same `Start Date` `2015-01-01`? And why does the new range start one day after Start in the first block and one day earlier in the second block?

Comment: @Stefan I just need to iterate over same start_date till the end of the year and populate end_date with that date for each date of the year.